# All triplet combinations, 6 values at a time

Tags: c++, python, algorithm, combinatorics

<strike>I am looking for an algorithm to efficiently to generate all three value combinations of a dataset by picking 6 values at a time.</strike>

I am looking for an algorithm to efficiently generate a small set of 6-tuples that cumulatively express all possible 3-tuple combinations of a dataset.

For instance, computing playing-card hands of 6 cards that express all possible 3 card combinations.

For example, given a dataset:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

The first "pick" of 6 values might be:

```
['a','b','c','d','e','f']
```

And this covers the three-value combinations:

```
('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'd'), ('a', 'b', 'e'), ('a', 'b', 'f'), ('a', 'c', 'd'),
('a', 'c', 'e'), ('a', 'c', 'f'), ('a', 'd', 'e'), ('a', 'd', 'f'), ('a', 'e', 'f'),
('b', 'c', 'd'), ('b', 'c', 'e'), ('b', 'c', 'f'), ('b', 'd', 'e'), ('b', 'd', 'f'),
('b', 'e', 'f'), ('c', 'd', 'e'), ('c', 'd', 'f'), ('c', 'e', 'f'), ('d', 'e', 'f')
```

It is obviously possible by:

- computing all triplet combinations
- picking 6 values
- computing all triplet combinations for those 6 values
- removing these combinations from the first computation
- repeating until all have been accounted for

In this example there are 2600 possible triplet combinations `(26*25*24)/(3*2*1) == 2600` and using the "brute-force" method above, all triplet combinations can be represented in around 301 6-value groups.

However, it feels like there ought to be a more efficient way of achieving this.

My preferred language is `python`, but I'm planning on implementing this in `C++`.

---

**Update**

Here's my python code to "brute-force" it:

```
from itertools import combinations
data_set = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')

def calculate(data_set):
  all_triplets = list(frozenset(x) for x in itertools.combinations(data_set,3))
  data = set(all_triplets)
  sextuples = []
  while data:
    sxt = set()
    for item in data:
      nxt = sxt | item
      if len(nxt) > 6:
        continue
      sxt = nxt
      if len(nxt) == 6:
        break
    sextuples.append(list(sxt))
    covers = set(frozenset(x) for x in combinations(list(sxt),3))
    data = data - covers
    print "%r\t%s" % (list(sxt),len(data))
  print "Completed %s triplets in %s sextuples" % (len(all_triplets),len(sextuples),)

calculate(data_set)
```

> Completed 2600 triplets in 301 sextuples

I'm looking for something more computationally efficient than this.

---

**Update**

Senderle has provided [an interesting solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12188268/267781): to divide the dataset into pairs then generate all possible triplets of the pairs. This is definitely better than anything I'd come up with.

Here's a quick function to check whether all triplets are covered and assess the redundancy of triplet coverage:

```
from itertools import combinations
def check_coverage(data_set,sextuplets):
  all_triplets = dict.fromkeys(combinations(data_set,3),0)
  sxt_count = 0
  for sxt in sextuplets:
    sxt_count += 1
    for triplet in combinations(sxt,3):
      all_triplets[triplet] += 1
  total = len(all_triplets)
  biggest_overlap = overlap = nohits = onehits = morehits = 0
  for k,v in all_triplets.iteritems():
    if v == 0:
      nohits += 1
    elif v == 1:
      onehits += 1
    else:
      morehits += 1
      overlap += v - 1
    if v > biggest_overlap:
      biggest_overlap = v
  print "All Triplets in dataset: %6d" % (total,)
  print "Total triplets from sxt: %6d" % (total + overlap,)
  print "Number of sextuples:     %6d\n" % (sxt_count,)
  print "Missed  %6d of %6d: %6.1f%%" % (nohits,total,100.0*nohits/total)
  print "HitOnce %6d of %6d: %6.1f%%" % (onehits,total,100.0*onehits/total)
  print "HitMore %6d of %6d: %6.1f%%" % (morehits,total,100.0*morehits/total)
  print "Overlap %6d of %6d: %6.1f%%" % (overlap,total,100.0*overlap/total)
  print "Biggest Overlap: %3d" % (biggest_overlap,)
```

Using Senderle's `sextuplets` generator I'm fascinated to observe that the repeated triplets are localised and as the datasets increase in size, the repeats become proportionally more localised and the peak repeat larger.

```
>>> check_coverage(range(26),sextuplets(range(26)))
All Triplets in dataset:   2600
Total triplets from sxt:   5720
Number of sextuples:        286

Missed       0 of   2600:    0.0%
HitOnce   2288 of   2600:   88.0%
HitMore    312 of   2600:   12.0%
Overlap   3120 of   2600:  120.0%
Biggest Overlap:  11

>>> check_coverage(range(40),sextuplets(range(40)))
All Triplets in dataset:   9880
Total triplets from sxt:  22800
Number of sextuples:       1140

Missed       0 of   9880:    0.0%
HitOnce   9120 of   9880:   92.3%
HitMore    760 of   9880:    7.7%
Overlap  12920 of   9880:  130.8%
Biggest Overlap:  18

>>> check_coverage(range(80),sextuplets(range(80)))
All Triplets in dataset:  82160
Total triplets from sxt: 197600
Number of sextuples:       9880

Missed       0 of  82160:    0.0%
HitOnce  79040 of  82160:   96.2%
HitMore   3120 of  82160:    3.8%
Overlap 115440 of  82160:  140.5%
Biggest Overlap:  38
```

Comment: Why do you need the six-tuples again?

Comment: I'm confused.  What does the picking 6 elements have to do with anything?  Why not just get all combinations of picking 3 elements?

Comment: If you need all triplet combinations then why pick 6 values first?

Comment: @Dhara: Because it is possible to express all triplet combinations in fewer goes when it is possible to pick 6 values at a time.

Comment: There are 2600 ways to pick three values from 26, but there are 230230 ways to pick six values from 26. Which combinations of six do you want to use? All of them? An arbitrary subset?

Comment: @senderle: I don't mind how the six values combinations are selected, I'm just looking for a set of six-value combinations that express all possible three-value combinations in less than `2600 / 2` "goes".

Comment: MattH, I don't follow your reasoning. To generate all combinations of three values from among 26, you have to perform 2600 calculations. Period. It doesn't matter whether you pick six values at a time or not. Indeed, breaking them up into groups of six slows you down because it causes duplications, which is why the algorithm you describe above has to precalculate the triplets. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @senderle: Yes. Does the analogy of computing hands of 6 cards expressing all possible 3-card triplets not help explain?

Comment: MattH, well, maybe. But your question says "I am looking for an algorithm to efficiently to generate all three value combinations of a dataset." If you want to literally _generate_ all three-value combinations of a 26-item dataset, you have to perform a minimum of 2600 calculations. Now it sounds like you don't actually want to _generate_ all three-value combinations at all. So you should consider editing your question to clarify.

Comment: @senderle: No, you've truncated my question. It says *I am looking for an algorithm to efficiently to generate all three value combinations of a dataset by picking 6 values at a time.*

Comment: @MattH -- If you have a deck of 26 cards and you are drawing hands with 3 cards, there are 2600 unique hands you could draw.  It doesn't matter if you partition your deck into sub-decks holding only 6 cards, there are still 2600 unique hands you can make from your deck.  Of course, you could say "How many hands can I make from this subdeck" and add that up for each subdeck, but then you haven't gotten all the combinations possible in your deck...

Comment: @mgilson: I said 6-card hands. I'm looking for a small number of 6-card hands that cumulatively express all possible 3-card combinations.

Comment: MattH, it's true that I truncated the sentence. I did so because as I understand these terms, "generate all three value combinations" directly contradicts "picking 6 values at a time." I understand what you're looking for now, but I still think you should rephrase your question.

Comment: Wow, really interesting analysis. I'm surprised by those results, but I can't tell whether or not they suggest that there's a smaller minimal set of sextuplets...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following produces correct results. It relies on the intuition that to generate all necessary sextuplets, all that is necessary is to generate all possible combinations of arbitrary *pairs* of items. This "mixes" values together well enough that all possible triplets are represented.

There's a slight wrinkle. For an odd number of items, one pair isn't a pair at all, so you can't generate a sextuplet from it, but the value still needs to be represented. This does some gymnastics to sidestep that problem; there might be a better way, but I'm not sure what it is.

```
from itertools import izip_longest, islice, combinations

def sextuplets(seq, _fillvalue=object()):
    if len(seq) < 6:
        yield [tuple(seq)]
        return
    it = iter(seq)
    pairs = izip_longest(it, it, fillvalue=_fillvalue)
    sextuplets = (a + b + c for a, b, c in combinations(pairs, 3))
    for st in sextuplets:
        if st[-1] == _fillvalue:
            # replace fill value with valid item not in sextuplet
            # while maintaining original order
            for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(st, seq)):
                if x != y:
                    st = st[0:i] + (y,) + st[i:-1]
                    break
        yield st
```

I tested it on sequences of items of length 10 to 80, and it generates correct results in all cases. I don't have a proof that this will give correct results for all sequences though. I also don't have a proof that this is a minimal set of sextuplets. But I'd love to hear a proof of either, if anyone can come up with one.

```
>>> def gen_triplets_from_sextuplets(st):
...     triplets = [combinations(s, 3) for s in st]
...     return set(t for trip in triplets for t in trip)
... 
>>> test_items = [xrange(n) for n in range(10, 80)]
>>> triplets = [set(combinations(i, 3)) for i in test_items]
>>> st_triplets = [gen_triplets_from_sextuplets(sextuplets(i)) 
                   for i in test_items]
>>> all(t == s for t, s in zip(triplets, st_triplets))
True
```

Although I already said so, I'll point out again that this is an inefficient way to actually generate triplets, as it produces duplicates.

```
>>> def gen_triplet_list_from_sextuplets(st):
...     triplets = [combinations(s, 3) for s in st]
...     return list(t for trip in triplets for t in trip)
... 
>>> tlist = gen_triplet_list_from_sextuplets(sextuplets(range(10)))
>>> len(tlist)
200
>>> len(set(tlist))
120
>>> tlist = gen_triplet_list_from_sextuplets(sextuplets(range(80)))
>>> len(tlist)
197600
>>> len(set(tlist))
82160
```

Indeed, although theoretically you should get a speedup...

```
>>> len(list(sextuplets(range(80))))
9880
```

... `itertools.combinations` still outperforms `sextuplets` for small sequences:

```
>>> %timeit list(sextuplets(range(20)))
10000 loops, best of 3: 68.4 us per loop
>>> %timeit list(combinations(range(20), 3))
10000 loops, best of 3: 55.1 us per loop
```

And it's still competitive with `sextuplets` for medium-sized sequences:

```
>>> %timeit list(sextuplets(range(200)))
10 loops, best of 3: 96.6 ms per loop
>>> %timeit list(combinations(range(200), 3))
10 loops, best of 3: 167 ms per loop
```

Unless you're working with very large sequences, I'm not sure this is worth the trouble. (Still, it was an interesting problem.)

Comment: That's a really interesting approach, I'll check it out thoroughly when I get to a keyboard. Thank you for the insight and effort you put into this and I'm glad I'm not the only one who thought this a fascinating problem!

Comment: So part of the duplication is that when you make every combination of the pairs `(0,1),(2,3),(4,5)`, `(0,1),(2,3),(6,7)`, all the triplets from `(0,1,2,3)` are repeated.

Comment: I've tried a couple of other approaches, without success. This is the best approach that I'm aware of.